Parallel execution of multiple tasks
I'm trying to create a list of tasks, that execute in parallel at a certain cron.
There are 5 config
Stream1 -\> config.Cron = \* 05 10 \* \* \*

Stream2 -\> config.Cron = \* 07 10 \* \* \*

Stream3 -\> config.Cron = \* 09 10 \* \* \*

Stream4 -\> config.Cron = \* 10 10 \* \* \*

Stream5 -\> config.Cron = \* 12 10 \* \* \*

That's my code
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

            foreach (var config in _options)
            {
                var crontabSchedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(config.Cron,
                  new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions
                  {
                      IncludingSeconds = true
                  });

                DateTime nextOccurrence = crontabSchedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);

                taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        var delay = Math.Max(0,
                            (int)nextOccurrence.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);

                        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);

                        _logger.LogInformation($"Stream {config.StreamName} start.");

                        await DoWork();

                        _logger.LogInformation($"Stream {config.StreamName} end.");

                        nextOccurrence = crontabSchedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }, cancellationToken));
            }

            if (taskList is not null && taskList.Any())
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
            }

I was expecting this kind of logs (Serilog)
'\[2024/04/15 10:05:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM1 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:05:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM1 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:07:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM2 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:07:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM2 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM3 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM3 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:10:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:10:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:12:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 start.

'\[2024/04/15 10:12:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 end.

Instead I get these
'\[2024/04/15 10:05:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM1 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:05:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM1 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:07:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM2 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:07:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM2 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM3 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM3 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:59\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:09:59\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:10:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:10:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM4 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:11:59\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:11:59\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 end. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:12:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 start. 

'\[2024/04/15 10:12:00\] Worker   Stream STREAM5 end.

I don't understand why stream 4 and 5 are executed two times, at the scheduled cron and 1 second before the schedule and it doesn't happen all the time.
Add some more logs, there are 6 config, the cron are scheduled to start at
10:39, 10:40, 10:41, 10:42, 10:43, 10:45
2024/04/16 10:37:34 Number of task 6 
2024/04/16 10:39:05 Default start. 
2024/04/16 10:39:05 Default end. 
2024/04/16 10:39:05 Default next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:39:05 
2024/04/16 10:40:04 STREAM1 start. 
2024/04/16 10:40:04 STREAM1 end. 
2024/04/16 10:40:04 STREAM1 next occurrence 4/16/2024 10:40:05 
2024/04/16 10:40:05 STREAM1 start. 
2024/04/16 10:40:05 STREAM1 end. 
2024/04/16 10:40:05 STREAM1 next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:40:05 
2024/04/16 10:41:04 STREAM2 start. 
2024/04/16 10:41:04 STREAM2 end. 
2024/04/16 10:41:04 STREAM2 next occurrence 4/16/2024 10:41:05 
2024/04/16 10:41:05 STREAM2 start. 
2024/04/16 10:41:05 STREAM2 end. 
2024/04/16 10:41:05 STREAM2 next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:41:05 
2024/04/16 10:42:04 STREAM3 start. 
2024/04/16 10:42:04 STREAM3 end. 
2024/04/16 10:42:04 STREAM3 next occurrence 4/16/2024 10:42:05 
2024/04/16 10:42:05 STREAM3 start. 
2024/04/16 10:42:05 STREAM3 end. 
2024/04/16 10:42:05 STREAM3 next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:42:05 
2024/04/16 10:43:05 STREAM4 start. 
2024/04/16 10:43:05 STREAM4 end. 
2024/04/16 10:43:05 STREAM4 next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:43:05 
2024/04/16 10:45:05 STREAM5 start. 
2024/04/16 10:45:05 STREAM5 end. 
2024/04/16 10:45:05 STREAM5 next occurrence 4/17/2024 10:45:05


YuOu might want to tell us where crontabSchedule is coming from.

Also please, format your code. (It's as simple as Ctrl+E-D in VS.)

The only suspicious thing I can see is converting the TotalMilliseconds to int. Try converting it to long, and see if it makes any difference. Ideally you should avoid converting your TimeSpans to numeric values. The Task.Delay has an overload with TimeSpan parameter.

@Ralf crontabSchedule come from NCrontab 3.3.3.
I tried to use Task.Delay with timespam param
await Task.Delay(nextOccurrence.Subtract(DateTime.Now), cancellationToken)
but unfortunately the problem is still there for some stream

I would suggest suggest adding some more logging (you have obviously a logging facility already in place) if that  NCrontab thing does what you expect it to do. Example does _options contain what you think it contains. Log that. Maybe its as simple as that some streams are twice in there. Log whats going into crontabSchedule.GetNextOccurrence and what comes out. Log delay and so on. Try to get as much data to look at. That should get you an idea what is really going on here.

Thank you @Ralf, yeah i filled my code with logs (i remove them from the code in the question body to make it more clear), in fact the number of task is correct, also the next occurrence of the cron is correct except for the stream that starts 1 second before the cron, That's what's don't make sense to me
